# "SD card is blank or has unsupported filesystems" message in Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sd-card

My Samsung Galaxy S4 showed  "SD card is blank or has unsupported filesystems". It then gave me the option to format my SD card, to which I reluctantly consented.

After having done so however, it proceeds to present me with the same message, "Blank SD card", regardless of how many times I insist in formatting.

After searching on Internet, I  found that apparently I should format the SD card from my computer. I don't have an adapter for microSD cards, so I connected my phone with a USB cable to my computer, and apparently my SD card refuses to show up there.

Also, for your information, it seems that neither my phone wants to recognize the SD card, for example if I try to transfer apps to my SD card my phone tells me I don't have a SD card.

So, is there anything I can do to resolve this issue? Should I buy a microSD adapter and hope that my computer will recognize the SD card then, or should I just buy a new SD card? Or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please see our [external-sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/external-sd/info) and take a closer look at [the graphic there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PIBwo.png) :) Have you tried the card in a different device? Sometimes there are incompatibilities.

Comment: Well, as previously mentioned I don't have a microSD card reader so I can't really follow that graph if connecting your phone to a computer with a USB cable is not sufficient.

Comment: That was just one point. Have you tried the card in any other device? Have you tried a different card in your device? Hard to tell which side the error is on without at least testing that. Whether the "other device" is another phone, or some SD card reader, depends on what's available – though using the latter makes it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your phone may not recognize your SD cards properly. Unfortunately, my phone is also one of them.

While each time it gives me the option to format my SD card, I tap "No" and then everything will be ok. All contents on my SD card can be shown normally. So, I think you may choose not to consent to format the card. Just shut down your S4 and power it on to have a try. Good luck.